# Data Import Wizard History

Tags: history-tracking, data-import-wizard

Is there a way to see more than just the last few imports done using the Data Import Wizard?

I see that the Data Import Wizard shows me the last three "Recent Import Jobs," but I want to see an import that was done 11 days ago. I don't need to see what data was imported. I just want to know if there was an import done by a specific person at a specific date and time.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The system only stores this data for the last seven days. If you have Event Monitoring, you can check the logs to see when/if an import occurred for a longer period. Otherwise, the best you can do is run a report and see if there are any records created/modified by the user in question.